# Xcode is not running updated code on the simulator or a connected physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm in the process of adding features to my app but whenever I run the app on iPad simulators or a connected physical device, none of my updated code appears. I have tried:

- Cleaning the build folder
- Deleting the derived data folder
- Rebooting the simulator
- Relaunching XCode
- Rebooting my computer
- Deleting the offending portions of my storyboard and code and
  re-typing them
- Resetting all content and settings and rebooting the simulator

So far nothing has worked. What else should I try?

Comment: Try changing an obvious thing and see if it work. Try removing a big label in your storyboard/swiftui view and see if it update.

Comment: I removed a large textfield and that did show up as a change in the simulator. For whatever reason, only a particular textview is being affected even though I have already deleted and recreated it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The text contained within the text view as attributed and would not update until I updated the attributed string in the view controller.